# How to optimize the calculation of the shortest time in a certain path in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database in Neo4j of modules that I imported through CSV. The data looks something like this. Each module has its name, it's module that is the successor, average time duration and another duration called medtime.

[image: Statistic Dependencies]

I have been able to import the data and to set the relationships through a Cypher Query script that looks like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:/users/Skelo/Desktop/Neo4J related/Statistic Dependencies/Simple.csv" AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
CREATE (n:Module)
SET n = row, n.name = row.name, n.mafter = row.mafter, n.avgtime = row.avgtime, n.medtime = row.medtime
WITH n

RETURN n
```

Then I have set the relationships like this:

```
Match (p:Module),(q:Module)
Where p.mafter = q.name
Merge (p)-[:PRECEEDS]->(q) 
Return p,q
```

Now to the point. I want to calculate the shortest path from a certain module to another, more specifically the time that it takes to get from a module to another and for this, I use the more or less copied part of the script from 
http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?8412907 and that is

```
MATCH p = (trop:Module {name:'BLSACXAMT0A_00'})-[prec:PRECEEDS*]->(hop:Module {name:'BL_LOAD_CLOSE'})
WITH p, REDUCE(x = 0, a IN NODES(p) | x + a.avgtime) AS cum_duration
ORDER BY cum_duration DESC
LIMIT 1
RETURN cum_duration AS `Total Average Time`
```

This, however, takes about 50 second to execute and that is outrageous. You can see it on the screenshot right below. The ammount of modules imported into the database is only about 2000 and what I want to achieve, is to successfully work with more than 50 000 nodes and perform such tasks much faster.

Other issue is, that the results are somehow suspicious. The format looks wrong, every number I have in the database has max 4 digits after the decimal point and I am only adding these values to zero, therefore if the result looks like this: 00103,68330,51670, I have serious doubts. Please, help me, if it is wrong, why is it so, and what can I do to correct it.

Neo4j claims that it is efficient and fast, therefore I presume that the fault is in my code (the performance of my computer is more than enough). Please, If you can, help me to shorten this time and explain the patterns needed to perform this.

[image: Neo4J - Calculation of the shortest time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypher does have a `shortestPath` function, see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html#_shortest_path. However this calculates the shortest path based on the number of hops and does not take a weight into account.

Neo4j has couple of [graph algorithms](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphalgo/GraphAlgoFactory.html) on board, e.g. Dijekstra or AStar. Unfortunately these are not yet available via cypher. Instead you have two alternatives to use them:

1) write an unmanaged extension to Neo4j and use GraphAlgoFactory in the implmentation. This requires to write same java code and deploy it to the Neo4j server. Using a custom CostEvaluator you can use the `avgTime` property on your nodes as cost parameter.

2) use the REST API as documented on http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html#rest-api-execute-a-dijkstra-algorithm-and-get-a-single-path. This approach requires to have the weight as a property on the relationship and not on a node (like in your data model)

Answer (score 2):

A few observations that should help:

1. You have several errors in how you are importing. These errors will create many more nodes than you think, and create the "suspicious" issue you raised:

   - Your file has multiple rows with the same `name`, but your import is creating a new `Module` node every time. Therefore, you are ending up with *multiple* nodes for some of your modules. You should be using `MERGE` instead of `CREATE`.
   - Your `mafter` property needs to contain a collection of strings, not a single string.
   - You are importing the numeric values as strings, so code such as `x + a.avgtime` is just doing string concatenation, not numeric addition. Furthermore, even if you did attempt to convert your strings to numbers, that would fail because your numbers use a comma instead of a period to indicate the decimal place.

   Try this for importing (into an empty DB):

   ```
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:/users/Skelo/Desktop/Neo4J related/Statistic Dependencies/Simple.csv" AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
   MERGE (n:Module {name: row.name})
     ON CREATE SET
       n.mafter = [row.mafter],
       n.avgtime = TOFLOAT(REPLACE(row.avgtime, ',', '.')),
       n.medtime = TOFLOAT(REPLACE(row.medtime, ',', '.'))
     ON MATCH SET
       n.mafter = n.mafter + row.mafter;
   ```
2. You also need to change your current `merge` query so that you can handle an `mafter` that is a collection. Note that the following query is designed to NOT create any new nodes (even if a name in `mafter` does not yet have a module node).

   ```
   MATCH (p:Module)
   OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:PRECEEDS]->(z:Module)
   WITH p, COLLECT(z.name) AS existing
   WITH p, filter(x IN p.mafter 
                  WHERE NOT x IN existing) AS todo
   MATCH (q:Module)
   WHERE q.name IN todo
   MERGE (p)-[:PRECEEDS]->(q)
   RETURN p, q;
   ```
3. You should create an index to speed up the matching of modules by name:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON :Module(name)
   ```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and let me first thank for the detailed analysis you provided, I appreciate the help. Somehow, when I did what you advised, I ended up with a name of a node like this 
"BLEVTDWH_W3
[DWTASK16, DWTASK29, DWTASK18, BLSCFA07_NEW, DWTASK05, DWTASK02, DWTASK15, DWTASK21, DWTASK31, DWTASK04, DWTASK13, DWTASK30, DWTASK09, DWTASK06, DWTASK19, DWTASK14, DWTASK07, DWTASK08,  "

Could you extend your answer please?

Comment: My query #1 (for importing the data) is getting the `name` property value from `row.name`. Does every row in your input file have the expected format?

Comment: Thanks, what you provided is actually correct, I interpreted some results falsely, mea culpa.